# How do you install a Maven2 plugin?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven-2, plugins, installation

I found this plugin for Google App Engine development that seems to be what I need.

But I have no idea how to install it.

I downloaded the JAR file from this page but I don't know where to put it:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've tried search for installation instructions but nothing is coming up. It seems like some kind of insider secret. Sorry - I'm new to Maven so I apologize if this should be obvious.

This is the pom I'm using:

http://code.google.com/p/thoughtsite/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't install it, Maven will do that for you. But you need to tell Maven from where it can download the plugin if the plugin is not available in the public repository. So, declare the plugin repository:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <repositories>
        [...]
        <repository>
            <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
            <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
            <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        [...]
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-gae-plugin-repo</id>
            <name>maven-gae-plugin repository</name>
            <url>http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    [...]
</project>
```

And use the plugin:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            [...]
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>[plugin version]</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

And let Maven do its job. This is actually documented in the [Usage](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/usage.html) page.

Comment: I actually did that but thought it didn't work because Eclipse didn't show any new menu options for the plugin.

Comment: @ovr I think that you are expecting too much from Eclipse, Eclipse won't suggest new Maven goals just because you declared a plugin in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @Pascal - I thought these goals would appear as menu options in Eclipse - http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: @Pascal - When I try to run those goals on the command line nothing happens either. I've tried running them as "mvn gae:run" and just as "gae:run"

Comment: @ovr They won't, but you can call them from Eclipse using a new custom configuration (Run As > Maven Build...).

Comment: @ovr Please update your question to show your pom.xml and relevant messages/errors/traces, I can't help you if I don't see anything :)

Comment: Thanks. I updated the q. The pom is taken from this project that I'm trying to build. http://code.google.com/p/thoughtsite/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml

Comment: Check out [my blog post about this matter](http://hamandeggs.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-gae-eclipse-maven/)

Comment: @ovr - Take a look at the pom.xml in jappstart. This is a working POM using the maven-gae-plugin. You just need to run maven w/ the relevant goals.http://github.com/tleese22/jappstart/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: @ovr The mentioned pom is contains too much system scope dependencies (which is an horrible practice if I may), it won't allow me to reproduce anything. By the way, I still don't know what "the problem" exactly is when you run `mvn gae:run` (you didn't post the console output). Several people have posted working configurations, did it help? If it didn't, please post the console output.